# How to pass an Angular Signal value to an NgRx selector

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

With regard to NgRx v16 new with Angular Signals, given:

```js
export const selectCustomer = (id: string) =>
  createSelector(selectCustomers, (customers) => customers[id]);
```

(common expression; taken from [Tim Deschryver's blog-post](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/parameterized-selectors#factory-selectors) on how to do this with NgRx, up to v15)

**Question 1**, how should this be done when I have a `Signal<string>` for  `id`?

FYI, currently I keep the selector as-was and use Angular's `toSignal`/`toObservable`, which seems like a bad detour:

```js
import { toSignal, toObservable } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop'
…
let id: Signal<string>;
…
const customer$ = toSignal(toObservable(id).pipe(
  switchMap(id => store.select(selectCustomer(id)))
));
```

Also, `toObservable` requires an [injection context](https://angular.io/guide/rxjs-interop#injection-context), so there are limitations where it can be used in the code.

---

And regarding memoization like

```js
import * as _ from "lodash";
…
export const selectCustomer = _.memoize((id: string) =>
  createSelector(selectCustomers, (customers) => customers[id])
);
```

**Question 2**, will such manual memoization then become unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With set withComponentInputBinding in appConfig I got it to work with using computed.

```js
// books.component.ts

export class BookDetailsComponent {
  private store = inject(Store);

  id = input<string>();
  book = computed(() => this.store.selectSignal(selectBook(this.id()))());
}

// app.config.ts

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
provideRouter(
  routes,
  withComponentInputBinding() // route id parameter => to id input signal
),
provideStore(reducers, { metaReducers, runtimeChecks }),
provideEffects(effects),
provideHttpClient(),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Thanks! For completeness, can you please add the appConfig snippet, I believe that is an important detail!

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**

i think you can do it as before (Tim's Versin) and don't need the interop package at all if you use ngrx v16. just call the signal to select from the store:

```js
customer$ = store.select(selectCustomer(id())
```

and if you want to get a signal back from the store directly just use

```js
customer = store.selectSignal(selectCustomer(id())
```

if you can't use ngrx v16 then you need to use the interop package like you did.

**Question 2**

Why do you want memoization for the selectorFactory? In your example all "source selectors" are already memoized. So the projector function just get's called if one of source selectors emit a new value and respect the id you used to return the calculated value. The created selector is also memoized so i don't know why you should memoize the factory function.

Comment: Thanks for your help; but from what I understand, `id()` is synchronous and hence `store.select(selectCustomer(id()))` will not react on future updates of `id()`, won't it? I have to give it a try, though.

Regarding question 2, the built-in memoization is only per selector instance; sometimes it is desirable to share memoization across instances, then this outer memoization is needed (also explained in Tim's post.)

Comment: Now i fully understand what you wanted to achieve. If you can't put it in the store the solution you created is suitable, but i think it would be the best way to put the id you want into the store or maybe you can select it directly from the route (getSelectors from the router-store package).